# How do I make ssh connection between macOS and Windows with bluetooth?

Tags: windows, macos, powershell, ssh, bluetooth

I want to make ssh connection between macOS and Windows(exclude Windows Subsystem for Linux, I'm asking about just Windows) with bluetooth.
Is there a way to do it?

I want to work Both Computers as a client and server.
In macOS, I'll use pre-installed ssh and sshd command, And https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/ use as windows ssh toolset.

I apologize that I am Japanese so My English is broken.

The following is environment of my computers.

(PC)
OS: Windows 10 Home x64
Bluetooth adapter: Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 for Desktop 7260HMWDTX1.R

(Mac)
Hardware: Mid 2012 MacBook Pro
OS: macOS 10.12.6
Supporting Bluetooth version: 4.0 (it maybe wrong?)

Comment: suddenly stackover seems to have a humour section ;)

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to make an SSH connection over Bluethooth. SSH requires TCP / IP and Bluethooth does not support TCP / IP.

Comment: well, bleutooth has many profiles,  including networking and some others. Also, strictly speaking,  SSH does not require TCP. It can be run over some other reliable tunnel.

Comment: If I am wrong please submit another answer and I'll remove mine!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have enough practical information to post a useful answer. But my points are still valid :).